# Where should the parallel region start in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to learn OpenMP, but the professor moved on to a different subject and I feel like I haven't learned a whole lot (or understood).

After looking at some solved questions here on SO I wrote this bit of code:

Working code now looks like this:

```
void many_iterations()
{
    int it, i, j;

    for (it = 0; it < NUM_ITERATIONS; it++)
    {
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            #pragma omp for private(j)
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                {
                    if (i == j) B[i][j] = A[i][j] * 2;
                    else B[i][j] = A[i][j] * 3;
                }
        }

        int **aux = A;
        A = B; B = aux;
    }


}
```

I also wrote a serial version (without the #pragma omp bits) and noticed that this version does not actually properly work (outputing A is different between the serial and this version). I then managed to change the two inner for loops to this working bit (correct output as far as I can tell):

```
for (index = 0; index < N * M; index++)
{
    int i = index / M, j = index % M;
    // rest of code here
```

This one does work, but I ran into a problem: running on two threads, it is just as fast as the serial version (with 2 inner fors) and when I tried running this with only one thread the execution time was a lot slower.

Reading online I understood that the parallel section should somehow start before the main for so that it reduces the overhead, but again, my output (A) is wrong.

So my issues are:

- How do I set `#pragma omp parallel` before the first for without ruining the code?
- Why is the serial version equal to the 2-thread version of the code with collapsed for loops?
- How should I make the code actually more efficient when running on multiple threads?

As a side note, I tried running the serial version with collapsed for loops and I got it to run a lot slower (just like the "parallel" version with 1 thread).

Edit: Trying to use `#pragma omp parallel` before the it loop:

```
void many_iterations()
{
    int it, i, j;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        for (it = 0; it < NUM_ITERATIONS; it++)
        {
            #pragma omp for private(j)
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                   {
                       if (i == j) B[i][j] = A[i][j] * 2;
                       else B[i][j] = A[i][j] * 3;
                   }

            #pragma omp single
            {
                int **aux = A;
                A = B; B = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: declare `private( j )`

Comment: Tried it with the parallel section starting with the 2 nested loops, but it doesn't change the output.

Comment: Then post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seems it wasn't working because I typed in 'i' instead of 'j', it runs just fine now. I have just one more question. Is there any way that I can start the parallel area before the iterations for? Just putting it there seems to mess with the output again and I guess it's because of the pointer swap.

Comment: Just add a `#pragma omp single` block to protect the two lines of your pointer swap and then the `#pragma omp parallel` can be moved up to enclose the loop over `it`.

Comment: I updated the code (last bit), but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Did I miss something?

Comment: needs `private(it)` too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126740/discussion-between-xzenon-and-gilles).